# What font is used on Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, fonts, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

What font is used for the interface in Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8?
Is this font free to use?

Comment: Related: [Determine windows system wide font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215988/determine-windows-system-wide-font) on stackoverflow.

Comment: Should be Segoe UI—this was introduced in Windows Vista.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Windows 8 Developer Preview uses Segoe WP in some places (mostly Metro styled apps and settings) and the Windows 7 default font Segoe UI on the desktop.

The Consumer Preview of Windows 8 will use Segoe WP everywhere.

The fonts are free to use. You get them if you install Visual Studio 2010 or other free developer tools from Microsoft for creating Windows Phone apps.

Answer (score 61):

By default, [Segoe UI](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=331) is the font used by Windows.

[image]

Windows XP used [Tahoma](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=19) for most user interfaces.

Windows 98 used [MS Sans Serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Sans_Serif).

Answer (score 50):

As [Jonno](https://superuser.com/users/536125/jonno) stated in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1038334/83682) Segoe UI is the current default.

You can check (and change) the exact font being used on your system by opening the control panel, going to "Appearance and Personalization"...

[image: Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization]

clicking "Change Window Glass Colors"

[image: Appearance and Personalization -> Change window glass colors]

clicking "Advanced Appearance Settings"

[image: Window Glass Colors -> Advanced Appearance Settings]

then selecting "Message Box" from the drop down menu to view the dialog box font settings for your system

[image: Advanced Window Appearance Settings]

Note: The screenshots and directions above are based on Windows 7. The exact steps to reach these settings may differ on other versions of Windows.

Answer (score 18):

> What font is used for the interface in Windows Phone 7 and Windows 8 Dev Preview?

For their [Metro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_(design_language)) design language, Microsoft use fonts from the [Segoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe) family. Windows Phone 7 uses Segoe WP.

> Is this font free to use?

Segoe WP is bundled with Visual Studio 2010, but (I'm guessing here) you are probably only allowed to use it in your developed software and related materials.

A very similar Segoe UI is [free for personal use](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=331), but must be licensed from Microsoft for commercial usage or for web development. Segoe UI is also closely related to [Frutiger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frutiger), which is sold commercially.

Comment: Segoe does not look like Frutiger at all. It, however, closely resembles [Adobe’s Myriad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myriad_(typeface%29).

Answer (score 8):

You can identify fonts by making a screenshot, cropping a sample of text and posting it at web-sites such as [WhatTheFont! « MyFonts](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).

Some say it is a version of Monotype's [Segoe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe) which has been alleged to be a rip-off of Linotype's Frutiger.

Both are commercial fonts, to use them on another computer you'll need to buy the font (licence) for that computer or install commercial software that has the font bundled with it.

<sup>(Dang, that grawity is fast on the draw)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The Segoe WP font used in Windows Phone 7 and in much of Windows 8. It is free to use under the Apache license when obtained via the [LightSwitch Metro Theme Extension Sample for Visual Studio 11](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/LightSwitch-Metro-Theme-7424397b). The fonts are stored in the folder `C#\MetroThemeExtension\MetroThemeExtension.Client\Presentation\Fonts`.

**Update**: The 6/19/2012 update to the sample removed the `Fonts` folder.